# Исчезновение письма. Возможно ли это?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Сейчас поголовно твердят, что в ближайшем будущем письмо исчезнет, что мы не будем писать от руки. Скажите, как вы относитесь к таким заявлениям? Мне кажется, что письмо действительно когда-нибудь да исчезнет, но это не придется на наш век. Вот я так думаю и всё. Оно ведь давным-давно появилось и на протяжении такого времени существует, а тут бац — исчезает. Ну не верится.

Comment: Мне кажется, оно не должно исчезнуть совсем даже через тысячу лет, если доживём.

Comment: Предсказания подобного рода непрестанно появляются с тех пор как люди стали думать о будущем. Некоторым уделяется больше внимания, потому что они более сенсационны, чем большинство других. Тем не менее, "сбываемость" предсказаний нисколько не  увеличивается, ни уменьшается.  Люди не становятся более умелыми в предсказании будущего, к сожалению, особенно что касается социальных явлений.

Comment: Проверьте, пожалуйста, мою пунктуацию...

Answer (score 1):

Только сейчас увидел, что автор понимает под "письмом" ***письмо от руки***. Оно - да, исчезнет. Фактически уже сейчас отмирает. Вот с книгами и с электронными текстами - сложнее. Книги - это вопрос культуры, не уверен, что они будут полностью вытеснены.  Ну, а электронные тексты можно теоретически заменить голосом, но не уверен, что это будет удачная замена. Письменный текст часто (а у меня - так всегда) воспринимается куда лучше устного...

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, письмо от руки исчезнет. Точнее не исчезнет, а станет такой же редкостью, как сейчас стенография. Вопрос только привычки и средств записи. Сейчас сделать небольшую заметку удобнее ручкой (электронный аппарат или слишком громоздкий, или мелкий, неудобный для печатания), но со временем, думаю, это уйдёт. Правда, не стоит отменять силу привычки, так что в ближайшие 50 лет полного отмирания письма я не ожидаю.